# Is it advisable to use Redis or Memcached as a cache for FILES?

Tags: performance, caching, redis, memcached

I have multiple configuration files which I need to read from disk and apply to many records. 
I need to improve this to increase performance.

I have two processes.

Process1: Update Configuration:

- This updates content configuration files.
- This can run from multiple locations.

Process2: Apply Configuration:

- This uses content of configuration files.
- This can run from multiple locations.
- At present, this is using direct file+n/w IO to read updated configuration files.

`Both processes are back-end and there is no browser involved here.`

Should I use Redis or Memcached as a cache for FILES ?

Note that file need to be read from a common location. They are being updated by another background process. Update can happen any time. Size of configuration files is 1K to 10K.

I want Process2 to access updated configuration files in fastest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is good choice as it preserves data in memory with optional persistence. So such approach does not have to touch hard drive.

The problem I can see here that every client needs to understand Redis and is to use some support library, e.g. in Java or whatever language you use.

Why to not use http itself, e.g. deploy some http file server. You can also provide version checking + caching, so client can store version of file on the server and use client-cache content if the server has same file and download it when it was changed. This is called HEAD, look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm

You just should use same approach as web itself has. Every browser downloads content, html, css, images etc. Best improvement, for you, is client side caching, e.g. css or images are stored in browsers cache and download only first type or when it was changed.

And if you dont want, you cant use exactly REST approach itself.

Comment: I want to clarify that there is no browser here.Both processes are back-end.

Comment: Sure, but the approach how to distribute data can be same. I wanted to show the principle on similar approach including browser and server. This is the same.